# Subversion control in scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

Is it possible for two persons to develop project in parallel in `Scratch` programming language? Is there anything like subversion control or code merging in `Scratch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sharing on the website and the backback for code merging. (login, and drag code items or sprites to the backpack at the bottomto make copies; then, drag in your project).

But that is nowhere like the management tools of subversion and other version control.

Alternatively, you could use BYOB, which saves a file, and control that with subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively...

If you have two `.sb2` files, you could use an external subversion control system to handle and merge the files. However, having version ids of the stacks of blocks would be hard if the `.sb2` files weren't regularly checked in, and without version ids, the program wouldn't know how to merge them (which version is the change vs. the original?). It would, however, be fairly simple for a program to merge Scratch files.

However, a JSON version control system for Scratch probably doesn't exist yet, so despite the (relative) simplicity of the task, most existing programs don't know how to merge Scratch 2 files.

Comment: Doesn't exist **yet**.

Comment: Scratch 3.0 is based on Blockly, and one should be able to extract the save XML in that case. [Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(workspace)](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Xml#.workspaceToDom) and [.domToWorkspace(xml, workspace)](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Xml#.domToWorkspace): ,

Comment: @Anm So Scratch 1.x and Scratch 0.x (which both afaik share the same format) are the only big problems.

Comment: It wouldn't be pretty, since there is no UI and the merges might get complicated. For instance, inserting a block above other blocks in a stack has a big impact on indentation in the XML, and thus can affect every line of XML following the inserted block in the stack.

Comment: @Anm So just unintentional, merge then pretty-print.

Comment: If you meant "unindent", then yes, I think that would work well with the XML export.  Again, this is just for Scratch 3.0, which isn't ready for prime time yet (but would probably work on other Blockly projects just fine).

Comment: @Anm Stupid autocorrect. Yes, that's what I meant. :-)